# statsmodels examples seem not to work

Tags: python, pandas, statsmodels

```
import statsmodels.formula.api as sm
import numpy as np
import pandas

url = "http://vincentarelbundock.github.com/Rdatasets/csv/HistData/Guerry.csv"
df = pandas.read_csv(url)
df = df[['Lottery', 'Literacy', 'Wealth', 'Region']].dropna()
print df.head()
mod = sm.ols(formula='Lottery ~ Literacy + Wealth + Region', data=df)
res = mod.fit()
print res.summary()
```

Spits back this ERROR after printing the table.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-f69caff21ed0> in <module>()
6 df = df[['Lottery', 'Literacy', 'Wealth', 'Region']].dropna()
7 print df.head()
----> 8 mod = sm.ols(formula='Lottery ~ Literacy + Wealth + Region', data=df)
9 res = mod.fit()
10 print res.summary()

TypeError: from_formula() takes at least 3 arguments (2 given)
```

This does not seem like acceptable behavior.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think it's because formula and data are not keyword arguments. Try to drop them from the call to ols.

Comment: Works for me.  Can you type `import statsmodels.api as sm; print sm.version.version` and `import patsy; print patsy.__version__` into a prompt and let me know what you get?

Comment: import statsmodels.api as sm; print sm.version.version
0.5.0.dev-1bbd4ca

Comment: import patsy; print patsy.__version__

Comment: drop the formula and data keywords did work.  I am having trouble understanding why 

    [http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/stable/example_formulas.html]

would state the examples as they did?

Comment: @user333700  , could you put you suggestion to me as the answer for this question.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(The guess in my comment was wrong)

Your version of statsmodels is too old. The documentation and example is correct for the released version of statsmodels 0.5.

The `data` keyword has been renamed from `df` since 0.5.0.dev-1bbd4ca.

So either you upgrade, which I highly recommend, or you use the old keyword name

```
mod = sm.ols(formula='Lottery ~ Literacy + Wealth + Region', df=df)
```

should work with the version that you have.

Comment: I got it via pip.  You think I should upgrade my pip packages?